# how to create development environment already created QA and stage environment in local server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

how to create development environment already created QA and stage environment i need help please i didnot know how my ex Admin did those two environment as well as what skill i require to create such environment?

Comment: do not ask generic questions like this, without showing that you put-in some effort in finding solutions; it is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

As a Dev-ops there are multiple tools out there, but you can start with the following two tools which are very simple to use and have a very small learning curve.

1. [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible)
2. [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Note: Some tools are needed as per the the needs of your application stack.